# What would you do in this situation?

Tags: engines, analysis

After black moved his rook, what would you do as white? I did not find the best move according to the chess engine; I'm wondering what ideas you have.

```
[FEN "1r2k2r/p1Q5/3p1qn1/4npp1/7p/1B6/PP1B1PPP/R3R1K1 b K - 0 1"]

1... Rbd8
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Black's queen is the only defender for the mate on f7 (the knight on e5 is pinned). This makes Bxg5 a very attractive move, as the black queen has nowhere to go (the only safe spot, Qf8, is met with Qxd8 and mate).

```
[FEN "3rk2r/p1Q5/3p1qn1/4npp1/7p/1B6/PP1B1PPP/R3R1K1 w - - 0 1"]

1. Bxg5!
```

Black can chase the white queen for a couple of moves but his position will collapse very soon.

Comment: This exercise is about _deflecting_ the Black Q from the defense of `f7`. It also has some tempo elements: `1... Rd7 (maybe hoping for 2. Bxf6 Rxc7 3.Bxh8 Nxh8 but then 4. f4) 2. Qxd7+ Kxd7 3. Bxf6` and Black is down a rook and a pawn.

Answer (score 0):

The Scenario here does not call for any Strategic plan but it is a tactical shot of Deflection and Queen gets overloaded with B*g5 move . Black is in a precarious position with no offence but to resist for sometime . Black has 2 knights and King in centre with Rooks not even joined to each other . White on the other hand has its Bishops pointing towards Black and Rooks yet to join the party and the Queen is keeping a close watch on the 7th rank .

Even if the Tactical B*g5 would not have been possible White should win with normal moves .